# Unix: Project Management with Make

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, makefile

My instructions are:

The steps necessary to produce this program are:

Compile cpp2html.c to produce cpp2html.o. (Important: the source code in this project is C, not C++, and so must be compiled and linked with gcc, not g++.)

Run the command

flex cppscanner.l
to produce the file lex.yy.c from the language description in cppscanner.l.

Compile lex.yy.c to produce lex.yy.o. (This often produces a warning message about extra tokens. Ignore it.)

Link the .o files to produce an executable program named cpp2html

Write a makefile that will carry out these steps. Your makefile should result in only the minimum required amount of steps when any input file to this process is changed. (Note: you will probably not be able to base this makefile upon my self-updating makefile as in the earlier part of the assignment. Instead, you will probably find it necessary to write this one from scratch.

Here is my makefile:

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
        gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
        mv a.out cpp2html

lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
        gcc -g -DDEBUG lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c:
        flex cppscanner.l

cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
        gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.c
```

What am I doing wrong here? I get an error message saying:

> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [cpp2html.o] Error 1
>
> Your makefile does not build 'cpp2html' when invoked:
> gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.c

This is due tonight, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the a reason you are using `mv` instead of just adding `-o cpp2html` ?

Comment: Shouldn't your `.c` -> `.o` rules include a `-c` parameter? Otherwise (as I believe the error implies), they'll try to link a full executable instead of just compiling to an object file. e.g.: `gcc -c -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.c`

Comment: The error message seems incomplete. What lines are present before `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`?

Comment: This was [a coursework assignment](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs252/latest/Directory/outline/index.html#but_topic_d8e621) from [CS 252 at Old Dominion University](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs252/).  Before reading answers, note that [the Academic Honesty policy](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs252/latest/Public/syllabus/index.html#academic-honesty) is very clear on the subject of submitting other people's work as one's own.  https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4206/

Answer (score 3):

It's complaining about the following:

```
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
        gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.c
```

This line is trying to compile `cpp2html.c` to `a.out`.

Change that to

```
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
        gcc -g -DDEBUG -c cpp2html.c
```

Do the same thing for the line that compiles `lex.yy.c` to `lex.yy.o`.  The `-c` option tells `gcc` to only generate the object file and write it to the `.o` file.

You can take advantage of other options and some built-in variables.  Here's a suggestion:

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
        gcc -g -DDEBUG -o $@ $?
```

`$@` evaluates to the name of the target.  `$?` evaluates to the list of dependencies (the `.o` files).  The `-o` option tells `gcc` to write the resulting binary to the specified file name instead of `a.out`.

You can also take advantage of implicit rules:

```
%.o : %.c
        gcc -g -DDEBUG -c $<
```

This will build any `.c` file to the corresponding `.o` file, so you don't need to repeat the same commands for `cpp2html.c` and `lex.yy.c`.

**Edit**

FWIW, here's how I'd structure the makefile (with annotations; assumes Gnu make):

```
# Variables used by implicit rules
CFLAGS=-g -DDEBUG -Wall -Werror  # flags for gcc
LFLAGS=                          # flags for flex, currently none
LEX=flex                         # lexer     
CC=gcc                           # C compiler

# Variables to make life easier
LSRCS=cppscanner.l                            # All of our flex source files
SRCS=cpp2html.c $(patsubst %.l,%.c,${LSRCS})  # All of our C source files
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,${SRCS})              # All of our object files
TARGET=cpp2html                               # Final target name

${TARGET} : ${OBJS}              
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^ # Explicit rule to build target
                                 # $@ expands to target name
                                 # $^ expands to list of all prerequisites

clean:
        rm -rf *.o $(patsubst %.l,%.c,${LSRCS})
```

That's it.  We're relying on *implicit* rules to build the `.l` file to a `.c` file, and to build the `.c` files to `.o` files.  The implicit rules use the `LEX`, `CC`, `LFLAGS` and `CFLAGS` variables to run the right commands with the right options.  We only need the single explicit rule to build our final executable.

The advantage of structuring a makefile like this is that you can add files to the project without having to add new rules.

I *think* all of the above is correct; my main box is shut down at the moment so I can't test it.  Refer to the [Gnu Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Top) for more details.

Comment: If you're going to suggest macros, why not `${CC}` and `${CFLAGS}` too?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Two reasons - one to minimize information overload, and two because I'm typing from my iPad with no external keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! Turns out, the makefile was correct, I was just having problems with the flex command. After moving all files from the directory into a new one and copying the blank files from the instructor's directory, the makefile worked.